# How to scroll to an element when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following website:
http://www.gameplay-universe.uphero.com/

You can see the "Skip to Content" link. I want when it's clicked the page to scroll to `div#content`. I am using the latest version of jQuery. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element - search my man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK here's the solution I've found:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Click event for any anchor tag that's href starts with #
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {

    // The id of the section we want to go to.
    var id = $(this).attr("href");

    // An offset to push the content down from the top.
    var offset = 60;

    // Our scroll target : the top position of the
    // section that has the id referenced by our href.
    var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;

    // The magic...smooth scrollin' goodness.
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 500);

    //prevent the page from jumping down to our section.
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li a").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

this gonna work for all links inside li elements.

Comment: Since I'm new to jQuery, which variables should I edit to make it scroll to `div#content onclick li.skip a`?

Comment: $("#skip a").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scrollTop($('div#content').offset().top)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I like to use whenever I want to enable a "scroll to" type of Jquery effect.

http://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/